# How to do an authentication with basic htttp pst and xcode?

Tags: objective-c, authentication, http-post

My propose is to do a login into a website to get my profile information
I have this code:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=Mike&passwd=whatever"]; 
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];


NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myweb.com/profile"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];  

NSURLResponse *response=nil;
NSData *data;  
data= [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:NULL];

NSString *content1 = [[NSString alloc]  initWithBytes:[data bytes]
                                              length:[data length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Page = %@", content1);`
```

Questions:

1. What I get from data is the login
   web over and over, what's wrong? the
   login doesnt work!
2. I have named the post variables username and passwd, because that's the name(tag) they             have in the html code. is that ok?
   Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it is HTTP shouldn't it be HTTPS?

With the given information it is very difficult to give you an answer. Maybe you clarify a little bit.

1) I assume with the "1-What i get from data is the login web over and over, what's wrong?" meant you get a web page. As a response on a post or get request you get back what the server will send you. The same as in a browser.

2) Yes.

Comment: Your code seems fine, I imagine there is something wrong with the post data your are sending. Can you include the url of the website you're trying to login to, plus the output of your NSLog?

Comment: I am trying to login to a joomla web: www.ambrosden.biz/administrator yes the response is right, if I try lo login with safari with wrong username/pass I get the login page over and over. BUt why it doesnt login???? Btw, in case is https, what changes i should make? Thanks

Comment: There could be a couple of things happening. I also once had trouble implementing a logon. Somehow the problems disappeared when I used asynchronous request and traced exactly what was going on. I never figured out what exactly was wrong with the synchronous response but maybe you go this route and have more control. I can post you an example if you like to. On HTTPS the URLString would be "https:// ... instead of "http:// ...

Comment: Oh and some more important things. If you look at the source code of the page there is more values to pass. There is a name "lang" (language) and there is a "option" and a "task" and a name="47db70c0557f15327b755574e1726b4d" I guess you have to pass all them with the post request also. Also there is some Javascript for the submit button and I wouldn't like to tell what else going on there.

Comment: Ok. I have you a new suggestion. Instead of trying to do the request yourself you can use a UIWebView and inject some Javascript at the end of the page and fill up the form and hit submit. If you google for "UIWebView inject javascript" there are some tutorials around.

Comment: You are right, I have tested the post method in ths web: http://hroch486.icpf.cas.cz/formpost.html and I am sending what I believe I am sending, and it is working. BUT probably I dont get the right variables names, or there is something else that the site is expecting me to send. Don't know. I have to find it out. Thanks!

Comment: Very well. By the way there are up an down arrows to vote an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to login to a joomla web: www.ambrosden.biz/administrator yes the response is right, if I try lo login with safari with wrong username/pass I get the login page over and over. BUt why it doesnt login???? Btw, in case is https, what changes i should make? Thanks
I am not allowed to post the log because it has hyperlinks, and I have taken screenshots, but aparently I am not allowed to upload images either.

This is the output deleting some links to avoid this restricton:

```
Page = <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

ambrosden - Administration

function setFocus() {
        document.login.username.select();
        document.login.username.focus();
    }

ambrosden

```
                <h1>Joomla! Administration Login</h1>

                        <div id="section-box">
        <div class="t">
            <div class="t">
                <div class="t"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m">
            <form action="index.php" method="post" name="login" id="form-login" style="clear: both;">
<p id="form-login-username">
    <label for="modlgn_username">Username</label>
    <input name="username" id="modlgn_username" type="text" class="inputbox" size="15" />
</p>

<p id="form-login-password">
    <label for="modlgn_passwd">Password</label>
    <input name="passwd" id="modlgn_passwd" type="password" class="inputbox" size="15" />
</p>
    <p id="form-login-lang" style="clear: both;">
    <label for="lang">Language</label>
    <select name="lang" id="lang"  class="inputbox"><option value=""  selected="selected">Default</option><option value="en-GB" >English (United Kingdom)</option></select> </p>
<div class="button_holder">
<div class="button1">
    <div class="next">
        <a onclick="login.submit();">
            Login</a>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
<input type="submit" style="border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 0px; height: 0px;" value="Login" />
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_login" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="672372a5278b2ba6d345ec69f792c547" value="1" /></form>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="b">
            <div class="b">
                <div class="b"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

                <p>Use a valid username and password to gain access to the Administrator Back-end.</p>
                <p>
                    Return to site Home Page</a>
                </p>
                <div id="lock"></div>
                <div class="clr"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="b">
                <div class="b">
                    <div class="b"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <noscript>
            Warning! JavaScript must be enabled for proper operation of the Administrator back-end.         </noscript>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="border-bottom"><div><div></div></div>
```